# PostgreSQL simple select not using index on big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I have a table "accounting_line" with about 304771383 rows

Then running a select to return single line:

```
select integervalue from accounting_line
where accounting_line.accounting_id = 2124651 and accounting_line.type_id = 13;
```

I have an index on columns (accounting_id, type_id), but index is not used...
Query is very slow, takes about 2 mins.
Any help please. It should be fast to select single row right?

Here is explain analyze of the select:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..3847029.00 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=91410.660..110394.859 rows=1 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 2
Workers Launched: 2
->  Parallel Seq Scan on accounting_line  (cost=0.00..3846025.20 rows=16 width=4) (actual time=104060.824..110387.831 rows=0 loops=3)
    Filter: ((accounting_id = 2124651) AND (type_id = 13))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 101590461
Planning time: 0.124 ms
Execution time: 110394.883 ms
```

Here is table DDL:

```
create table accounting_line
(
    id serial not null constraint accounting_line_pk primary key,
    accounting_id integer constraint fkio32oufjgdbf586bpr58j892d references accounting,
    type_id smallint constraint fknx7ej42yfoxdicpo8yhat8gto references accounting_type,
    doublevalue real,
    integervalue integer,
    percentage boolean default false not null
)
;

alter table accounting_line owner to orgdb
;

create index accounting_line_accounting_id_type_id_index
    on accounting_line (accounting_id, type_id)
;
```

Comment: Does updating the statistics using `analyze accounting_line;` change anything?

Comment: No i did that and No change...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually you where partially correct. While analyze on the accounting_line did nothing, after vacuuming, analyzing and reindexing everything it started working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While analyze on the accounting_line did nothing, after vacuuming, analyzing and reindexing everything it started working again